# Unsure About Process.CloseMainWindow() VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am using the following code to close a dos application process based on its name

```
For Each proc As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If proc.ProcessName = "MyDosApp" Then
           proc.CloseMainWindow() 
           proc.Close()
        End If
 Next
```

After the process is closed, I need the contents of Textbox1 to be cleared.

I have read on the MS docs about CloseMainWindow() and WaitForExit() and I believe I am in the right area but just not sure how to use these to clear the Textbook contents after the process has closed and disappeared.

Any help appreciated.

Ian

Comment: Just call TextBox1.Clear() after proc.WaitForExit()?

Comment: If you have read the documentation for the `CloseMainWindow` method, why are you calling it at all? *"Kill is the only way to terminate processes that do not have graphical interfaces"*. Does a console application have a GUI?

Comment: The reason why I chose to use CloseMainWindow is because when the Dos app closes, it saves data settings back to a config file.

From what I read, using the Kill method would terminate the process immediately which would not give any time for the data settings to be written back to the config file.

My understanding is that CloseMainWindow gracefully closes allowing time for Dos app to save its settings.

Comment: Using Just call TextBox1.Clear() after proc.WaitForExit() as suggested by Martheen did what I wanted. I need to revisit the docs again re-read about how this works.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Just call TextBox1.Clear() after proc.WaitForExit() as suggested by Martheen did exactly what I wanted.

```
For Each proc As Process In Process.GetProcesses
    If proc.ProcessName = "MyDosApp" Then
       proc.CloseMainWindow()
       proc.WaitForExit()
       Textbox1.clear() 
       proc.Close()
    End If
Next
```